# Can I link an XCUITest target to a different Project's app target OR use XCTest/XCUITest outside of a UI Test Bundle target?

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcuitest

I am currently building out a test suite in an Xcode workspace that contains 3 existing projects. 2 App projects and a common framework project. Both apps are very similar in regards to UI with some minor differences.

I am trying to find a way to share the XCUITest framework I made for **App A** with **App B**.

Currently, **App A** has a test target set inside of its AppA.xcodeproj. All of **App A**'s tests are doing great and easy to maintain. I need to extend this to **App B** and refactor **App A**'s framework to only the App A exclusive bits so **App A** and **App B** can share the common XCUITest framework code base from a central base.

I have tried to create a new project, move over the UI test code and point the new UI Test target at **App A**'s executable, but I could not figure out how to get the option to show. 
I set the **App A** app as a Target Dependency in the New Project's test target > Build Phases tab, but no luck. I was able to set **App A**'s target in the new test target's scheme but still landed on an error.

```
Assertion Failure: CommonBasePage.swift:21: failed: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", 
"No target application path specified via test configuration: <XCTestConfiguration: 0x60400014e910>
                      testBundleURL:file:///Users/user.name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Debug-iphonesimulator/NewTestTarget-Runner.app/PlugIns/NewTestTarget.xctest/
             testBundleRelativePath:(null)
                  productModuleName:NewTestTarget
                        testsToSkip:(null)
                         testsToRun:NewBasePage/testExample
                 reportResultsToIDE:YES
                  sessionIdentifier:<>
         pathToXcodeReportingSocket:(null)
          disablePerformanceMetrics:no
    treatMissingBaselinesAsFailures:no
                    baselineFileURL:(null)
           baselineFileRelativePath:(null)
              targetApplicationPath:(null)
          targetApplicationBundleID:(null)
     testApplicationDependencies:
{...
```

I'm assuming targetApplicationPath:(null), targetApplicationBundleID:(null) should have legit target values but I'm unsure where else to look in order to set them.

I gave up on that and tried to create a new project & target as a Cocoa Touch Framework to shift the common code to a central point but was not able to import XCTest, which my framework depends on for XCUIApplication and XCUIElement fields.

`import XCTest //Causes "Cannot load underlying module for 'XCTest'"`
I tried adding XCTest.framework to the targets "Link Binary with Libraries" section under build phases but no luck.

Is there a way to work with the XCTest framework outside of a test target? 

OR
Is there a way to point one project's test target at another project's app target?

Answer (score 2):

You can link XCTest and any other framework to anything. Make sure you have `$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks` in both `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` and `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`.

Making framework for shared code is a good idea.